# Share shiro environment between multiple modules

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication, wildfly, shiro

I have a J2EE application consisting of two modules:

- An EJB module, with classes that implement the business logic of the application. It uses JPA for data persistence.
- A WAR module build with JAX-RS (RestEasy) that implements a RESTFul service for interact with my ejbs.

The application is deployed inside an EAR in wildfly 8.2.0.Final
I need to secure the REST api with Basic Authentication using users information stored in the database.

I'm trying to use Apache Shiro 1.2 for this purpose: I've modified web.xml like these:

```
<!-- Resteasy configuration -->

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ShiroFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ShiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

and added a shiro.ini file in WEB-INF:

```
[main]
cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

userRealm=myapp.realm.UserRealm
securityManager.realms=$userRealm

[urls]
/* = authcBasic
```

then defined UserRealm class:

```
public class UserRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

    @EJB
    AppUserController appUserController;

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals) {
        // ....
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = (String) token.getPrincipal();
        AppUser user = appUserController.findByUsername(username);
        SimpleAuthenticationInfo authenticationInfo = new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                null,
                getName()
        );
        return authenticationInfo;
    }

}
```

where AppUserController is a `@Stateless` ejb that manage users account.
Now I have the first (little) problem: at runtime the appUserController ejb is always null. 
I know that this is because the UserRealm instance is not a managed object, and I bypassed this by getting an instance via JNDI

```
 InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
 appUserController = (AppUserController) context.lookup("java:global/...../AppUserController");
```

but I would like to know if there is a way to use managed @EJB.
I tried to make `UserRealm` a `@Stateless` but it doesn't work.

Moreover I had another (major) problem. I would like to access the `SecurityUtils.getSubject()` inside the ejb module. Is there a way for share the shiro environment between multiple modules inside the same EAR?
I read so many examples but I could not find complete information

thanks, in advance...

Comment: With Java EE, I hope you're not forced to still use J2EE, you can package your EJB in a `.war` archive. The EnvironmentLoaderListener should 'inject' the 'security context', making it available using `SecurityUtils.getSubject()`.

Comment: @zellus thanks for reply. Unfortunately a war cannot depends on another war (not in a "standard" way) and I had many issues in the past. Of course, I could package all my classes in a single war but my project will grow much in the near future so I'm looking for a modular solution.